# Remove ~ from a url using mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I have little hosting for developing with Rocky Linux and I'm  using CentOS control web panel and I'm using accounts but to get access to them I need to go to `example.com/~user` or `~user2` or `~user3`.

I want to remove that tilde or hide or I want to be able to open the content of `example.com/~user` and that it can be viewed by entering `example.com/user`.

How can I do this procedure using the mod_rewrite mod, or is there another procedure that allows me to hide the tilde `~` because it represents a security problem.

Comment: This looks like [Apache's per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)? In which case, you can't "simply" remove the `~` as it is part of the syntax.

Comment: "hide the tilde ~ because it represents a security problem" - What is the "security problem"?